# bad conversion from html to pdf with htmldoc

Tags: html, htmldoc

I'm trying to convert HTML to PDF using **htmldoc**, but even basic HTML does not convert properly, I have this HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>pdf test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td width="50%">
                a
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>
                    some address
                </p>
                <p>
                    some other text
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                test<br>
                test2<br>
                asdfasdf<br>
                qwerqwer<br>
                fasdfasdf
            </td>
            <td>
                bla
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

but it renders like this: [test.pdf](http://boob.pocebo.sk/test.pdf) using this command:

```
htmldoc --webpage --color --charset utf-8 -t pdf14 --size a4 test.html -f test.pdf
```

it's `HTMLDOC Version 1.9svn`, I tried to change charset, add `thead, tbody` etc and nothing helped .. do you know what can be the problem ?

also it doesn't accept `style="padding: 10px"` in that paragraphs etc

Comment: Bump. Same problem. 1.9 doesn't appear to ever have been finished and 1.8 doesn't support utf8. The easy solution is to use another pdf library. Unfortunately, my client is the government and they're forcing me to use this. Strategies for utf8 encoding for version 1.8, or fix for 1.9 not displaying in FF/IE needed.

Comment: Your test.pdf URL pointing to domain pocebo.sk is unresolvable, for me at least.

Answer (score 1):

The command:

```
htmldoc --size universal --webpage -t pdf --firstpage p1 -f test.pdf test.html
```

renders the page well for me. It is unclear from the original question whether the options for utf-8 color and pdf type you entered are actually needed for your result or are actually the cause of the incorrect rendering.